# Facing error while login to the ecr from local machine(windows)

Tags: docker, amazon-ecr

I’m encountering an error while login to the ecr from local machine (Windows).

I have used this command for login:

```
aws ecr get-login-password --region ap-south-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 26224922****.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
```

However I am getting the following error:

> ```
> unknown flag: --password-stdin
> See 'docker login --help'.
> Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>
> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
> ```

Comment: I tried this, no joy: C:\Users\xxx>CHCP 1252
Active code page: 1252

C:\Users\joe>aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login -username joe -password-stdin xxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
accepts at most 1 arg(s), received 2
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Comment: The command used to work on this same windows laptop ...